# Two Step Build Process Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, amazon-cloudfront

I am creating a Cloudfront Service for my organization. I am trying to create a job where a user can execute a Jenkins Job to update a distribution.

I would like the ability for the user to input a Distribution ID and then have Jenkins Auto-Fill a secondary set of parameters. Jenkins would need to grab the configuration for that Distribution (via Groovy or other means) to do that auto-fill. The user then would select which configuration options they would like to change and hit submit. The job would then make the requested updates (via a python script).

Can this be done through some combination of plugins(or any other means?)

Comment: How about a pipeline using two [userInputs](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204986450-Pipeline-How-to-manage-user-inputs), or a parameterized pipeline with one?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with pipeline.  Would those two userInputs occur at different times?  IE the first input would be Distribution ID and the second one would be preloaded with current Distribution configs where the user can choose to alter them?

Comment: In my understanding yes, this should be possible. The first input asks for the `DistributionID`, then comes some code that fetches the config, then another input where each parameters `defaultValue` is preset with a config value.

Comment: Awesome!  Do you know of any tutorials that make use of this with pipeline?

Comment: No I don't know any. Just use the sample pipeline from the link I provided above. You can actually copy/paste the sample pipeline. Try to e.g. duplicate the input stuff to learn how this stuff is working.

Comment: @StefanHanke it sounds like you could turn these comments into a decent answer. I've only read about pipelines but it sounds like you've actually used them, even a little.

Answer (score 1):

```
// the first input requests the DistributionID from a user
stage 'Input Distribution ID'
def distributionId = input(
    id: 'distributionId', message: "Cloudfront Distribution ID", parameters: [
    [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', 
        description: 'Distribution ID', name: 'DistributionID'],
])
echo ("using DistributionID=" + distributionId)

// Second
// Sample data - you'd need to get the real data from somewhere here
// assume data will be in distributionData after this
def map = [
    "1": [ name: "1", data: "data_1"],
    "2": [ name: "2", data: "data_2"],
    "other": [ name: "other", data:  "data_other"]
]
def distributionData;
if(distributionId in map.keySet()) {
    distributionData = map[distributionId]
} else {
    distributionData = map["other"]
}

// The third stage uses the gathered data, puts these into default values
// and requests another user input.
// The user now has the choice of altering the values or leave them as-is.
stage 'Configure Distribution'
def userInput = input(
 id: 'userInput', message: 'Change Config', parameters: [
 [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: distributionData.name, 
    description: 'Name', name: 'name'],
 [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: distributionData.data, 
    description: 'Data', name: 'data']
])

// Fourth - Now, here's the actual code to alter the Cloudfront Distribution
echo ("Name=" + userInput['name'])
echo ("Data=" + userInput['data'])
```

- Create a new pipeline and copy/paste this into the pipeline script section
- Play around with it

I can easily imagine this code could be implemented in a much better way, but at least, it's a start.